# Differences between MSBUILD vs VS2008 build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, msbuild, continuous-integration

I'm trying to set up a continuous integration process, where a server will build a VS2008 .SLN file and do some other actions.

When building from Visual Studio, everything works well.
However, when building using the CI server (which uses MSBUILD), the build fails for many MSB3191 (Unable to create directory ... )

In my SLN, various projects have a non-default output path, since i am copying all their outputs into one location, which is what seems to be causing the problem.

What is the difference between MSBUILD and the build used in VS? How come one succeeds while the other fails?

Also, what is a good practice to avoid this sort of issues?

Here's the output from MSBUILD:

"D:\MasterBuild_Dev\tlv_Platform\UBUILD\RecordersAutoFwk\Main.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\MasterBuild_Dev\tlv_Platform\UBUILD\Regression Automation Framework\Actions\Common\Common\EM.Licensing.csproj" (default target) (46) ->
(PrepareForBuild target) -> 
  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(790,9): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "........\RecordersAutoFwk\Main\bin\Debug\lib\". Cannot create "D:\MasterBuild_Dev\tlv_Platform\UBUILD\RecordersAutoFwk\Main\bin\Debug\lib" because a file or directory with the same name already exists. [D:\MasterBuild_Dev\tlv_Platform\UBUILD\Regression Automation Framework\Actions\Common\Common\EM.Licensing.csproj]

Comment: Could you please run msbuild Solution.sln /verbosity:diag > log.txt and show log lines related to error?

Comment: Did you try to build it locally using MSBuild?  Does it fail in the same way as on the build server?

Comment: trying both suggestions.

Comment: added MSBUILD output from build machine

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, I'd have to say that one of your accounts has permissions issues on the server.

What acount does VS run under? What account is MSBuild running under?

Comment: It is not related to permissions. I've basically set a bunch of projects' output paths to the same location. Whenever the folder is created at first, it is fine. The next project that wants to create this folder fails as it is already created (that's my assumption, need to confirm).

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes get locking clashes like this when im running msbuild using multiple cores - with the /maxcpucount:n, then it seems that one of processes is locking the folder for the other and then i get something like this.
Not using the switch fixes it, doesnt happen on all sln just some. 
Your not using a postbuild command to do the copying, rather than the build output path?

It would help if we knew your msbuild command?

Comment: Not sure, as Teamcity is the one invoking the build. In the meantime i switched to copy as a post build command, works fine.